# Set navigation bar separator color for screen transition in Swift (iOS 13/14)?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, shadow, uinavigationbarappearance

I have 2 screens with a common navigation controller and common navigation bar. The first screen should have no separator, the second one should have a separator of a custom color.

Code I tried:

1)

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = ...//some image with an appropriate color
```

2. 

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.shadowImage = navBarSeparatorColor.as1ptImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

It seems the first chunk of code works for ios 12 and that is all. Nothing works for iOS 13 or 14.

Note: there are some similar questions but their "solutions" don't work for iOS 13 and there are no questions for iOS 14 at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think on iOS 13, you need to set the appearance object inside `navigationBar`, for example:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
    }

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = .red
    }

}
```

Please note there are other appearances: `compactAppearance` and `scrollEdgeAppearance`. Instead of `shadowColor`, you can also set `shadowImage` as well.

Comment: thanks, already tried that. The problem is on iOS 13/14 there is a permanent dark line. You will see it if you set `shadowColor` to any color with transparency (for example `clear`)

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov set it to `nil`

`navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = nil`